# How can I tell if an element reference does exist in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

If an element is hidden in first render (for example the element is in an if statement scope which has evaluated as false, so won't get rendered), and some event makes it appear (if statement evaluate as true) the inner element reference gets updated after render. This works absolutely fine.

But in case the opposite event flow (first is true, than gets hidden by some event), the element reference does not get updated after render, still shows the original id instead of null or empty string. In this case if I call JsInterop with that element reference, it would give an error that element does not exists (which is obviously true). The problem is that the element reference still has the former id, it didn't get changed after render.

The question is how can I tell if an element is visible (rendered, existing) or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor does not destroy the ElementReference object. It is persisted for further usage. But it is always populated with new data; that is the insurrected ElementReference object gets a new id. Thus you can always compare two consecutive values of the id

You can set an element reference to its default value:

```
elementRef = default(ElementReference);
```

This is equivalent to setting a reference object to null.

And you can check weather an element reference does exist like this;

```
if (EqualityComparer<ElementReference>.Default.Equals(elementRef, 
                                             default(ElementReference)))
 {
     // Does not exist...      
 }
```

Play with this code, and see that whatever you've said is wrong, unless I didn't get you.

```
@page "/"


@if (display)
{
    <div @ref="elementRef">Welcome to your new app.</div>
}

<button @onclick="@(() => display = !display )">Toggle</button>
<button @onclick="ConsoleWrite">Console</button>
@code{ 
    private bool display = true;
    ElementReference elementRef;

    private void ConsoleWrite()
    {
               
        Console.WriteLine(elementRef.Id);

        if (!EqualityComparer<ElementReference>.Default.Equals(elementRef, default(ElementReference)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("return false");
        }

        // Set the element reference to its default value
        elementRef = default(ElementReference);

        if (EqualityComparer<ElementReference>.Default.Equals(elementRef, default(ElementReference)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Return true after being set to its default value");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("elementRef.Id is null now" + elementRef.Id);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work. The comparer results in false, and the elemenetRef id stays the same after the element has been hidden and the component got rerendered. Also I don't think that ElementReference can be destroyed since it is a struct, so it just gets overridden by the new value it should get before OnAfterRender() is called.

Comment: After startup, I pressed the console button, this is the output:
return false
Return true after being set to its default value
elementRef.Id is null now

this is after pressed the toggle then the console again: 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Return true after being set to its default value
blazor.webassembly.js:1 elementRef.Id is null now

Comment: You explicitly set the element reference to its default value in ConsoleWrite method. If I restart, and press the toggle first (hide the text) than press the ConsoleWrite button, this is what I get:
return false
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Return true after being set to its default value
blazor.webassembly.js:1 elementRef.Id is null now

As you can see, if I do not set the element reference back to its default value "by hand" It does not get updated by the time OnAfterRender gets called.

Comment: Although this looks a workaround, but I can just set it back to default when I hide the element. I mark your answer as a good one, since it helped me, thanks a lot, but I still would be interested how to get it work out of the box... Thanks again!

Comment: I'd suggest you post an issue in github requesting the Blazor team to consider an out of the box feature...